# Excel copy cell value to another cell if cell value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When a cell (A1) value is changed, it will be copied to another sheet (sheet3) in particular column (c)each time creating new cell.
the code works fine if cell value in A1 is manually entered, but here i have formula /paste link in A1. and with this formula, its not automatically updating.
Another challenge is I  wanted to copied to sheet1 in another excel(Amount) kept in same folder.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
    ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    intLastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Add our value to the next row...
    Sheet3.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "C") = Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's looks like easier but not getting clicked,,,quite interesting  too, if U select cell A1 press F2 and Enter then it works ,,, I've tried SEND KEY also but not working ,,, put this question on StackOverflow !!

Comment: ,, check my post below I've solved the issue !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**::Caveat::**

The *Worksheet **C**hange event* works when content in a cell changes, and while the *Worksheet **S**election Change event* works whenever a new cell is selected.

In your case whenever you either enter data in Cell `A1` or recalculate it, the Macro copies every new value to another sheet in new row.

But when Cell `A1` is linked with formula it doesn't works, the reason is in that case neither *Worksheet **C**hange* or ***S**election Change* works.

Therefore I would like to suggest **Worksheet **C**alculate** event, because it triggers Macro whenever the Sheet calculates any formula, as happens in your case, since Cell `A1` is linked with formula cell.

```
Private Sub CalCopy()

 Workbooks.Open "C:\Yourfolder\satyam.xlsx"
 a = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & a).Value = Workbooks("1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  Workbooks("satyam.xlsx").Close

 End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("A1").Value = Range("H1") Then
      
       Call CalCopy
     End If
    
    End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- Cell `A1` is linked with the Cell `H1`, has a formula.
- As soon you change data in source cells linked with the formula in Cell `H1`, Excel gets new values in both Cell `H1` & `A1`.
- And then the *Worksheet Calculate event* triggers the Macro `CalCopy`, copies value from Cell `A1` into `Sheet1` in another Workbook as new row/record .

**N.B.**

- Use both the VBA macros as **S**tandard Module.
- Save the Workbook as Macro Enabled `1.xlsm`.
- You need to change File path as needed.
- You may adjust cell references in the code as needed

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, it worked fine . Only one thing, I stuck as mentioned in my initial question.

Comment: If sheet1 and sheet2 are in one excel , it worked fine. But  here sheet1 is in one excel and sheet2 is another excel e.g. "satyam" ,and its .xlsx format.so what to put at the place of "sheet2"? How to give the path?

Comment: Hi @user3287723 ,,, glad to help you,,, my solution addresses your core issue,,, why your code was not working I've already explained in CAVEAT section,,,! Now about your another issue that how to use shown VBA code with Workbook is CLOSED,  What U have to do is add this code row in `Private Sub CalCopy()` at 1st row `Workbooks.Open "C:/myfolder/satyam.xlsx"`  (adjust Fie path as your  need), and these 2 row at  4 & 5th , `ActiveWorkbook.Save`,
`Workbooks("satyam.xlsx").Close`, now one more thing since my suggested method is working for you so you may mark it as ANSWER and well Up Vote also ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh I tried as per advise following code                                                    Private Sub CalCopy()
Workbooks.Open "C:/Users/satya/OneDrive/Desktop/satyam.xlsx"

a = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & a).Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Workbooks("satyam.xlsx").Close


End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("A1").Value = Range("F1") Then
      
       Call CalCopy
     End If
    
    End Sub

Comment: even with above code, when open the coded excel, it also opens another excel- satyam.xlsx and showing the above error  msg

Comment: You have not written the Error msg U r getting,,, and if ONEDrive is a folder on cloud then it will not work,,, confirm me the error & about One Drive!!

Comment: I little bit modified the code and I got this error. "Run time error 1004, Method ' Open' of objects workbook failed. [Private Sub CalCopy()

Workbooks.Open "D:\satyam.xlsx"

a = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & a).Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Workbooks("satyam.xlsx").Close


End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("A1").Value = Range("F1") Then
      
       Call CalCopy
     End If
    
    End Sub
]

Comment: @ Rajesh, The satyam.xlsx continue to show opening up until I press esc button. and then at the [Workbooks.Open "D:\satyam.xlsx" ] level showing error message run time error '1004'

Comment: @user3287723,, nothing wrong with command,, do this ,,,  Open any workbook then Go to File ,, Options ,,Trust Center.
Click on Trust Center Settings...
Under Macro Settings, make sure Trust access to the VBA project object model is checked.   Then close Excel & Reload then use the code I've suggested.

Comment: sorry I tried everything as per the advice . but its not working

Comment: @user3287723 could you share both Workbooks with me & let me check what is going wrong !!

Comment: Sure, How to send, by email? Or any option here to share?

Comment: @ Rajesh can I have email Id?

Comment: @user3287723  you can find my mail Id with my profile ,, please check my Superuser Profile Page .

Comment: I  Sent the mail.

Comment: Thanks got the mail and worked fine now. after changing the code..

Comment: @user3287723 ,, glad to help you keep asking ☺

Comment: one issue found, if any of the cells in "H" column changed,  it also copies the value in A1 cell to defined excel. I expect the value from A1 copies only when the value in H1 is changed. As i want to apply the similar formula from H2 cells to B column in the satyam.xlsx

Comment: I want to apply similar formula to I1  to B1 in 1.xlsx and copy to C column in satyam.xlsx sheet

Comment: @user3287723,,, try Worksheet Change Event for H1 only,,, and use same method for I1  to B1 what has been used previously !!

Comment: In worksheet change event, also its copying the the H1 value, infact if any of cell value is entered, its copying the H1 value to another excel

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Change event rather than SelectionChange.

Comment: I used the change event but it didnt worked